# Definition of <E>

Tags: java

I am very confused as to what `<E>` means. I am confused as to what is to be put in place of the E. I have been told that types could be put there such as Integer or Double. But I have also been told that ArrayList or LinkedList could be placed there. If anyone could clarify it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's just a placeholder to indicate **any type**.

Comment: @asgs: I'd say that it indicates any specific type. To avoid generating confusion with `?` which stands for any unspecified type. On the first you can make assumptions but you can't on the latter.

Comment: @Jack, totally agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`E` is a [**type variable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_variable). It's a variable and a place holder for a specific type.

This kind of syntax is used with [parametric polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism) when you want to tell that a specific class is parametrized over a type which is not specified.

This means that you can write code that relies on the fact that `E` is a specific type with a deegree of specification that is given by some constraints you can add, eg `<E extends MySuperType>`. And you can use `E` to refer to the generic type throughout the class definition.

You have been told right: since a variable is nothing more than a placeholder it can contain a concrete type like a `Double`, but even an `ArrayList<Double>` or finally also an `ArrayList<?>`, which is a collection of unspecified type. `?` is another special [keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) in [Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 2):

`<E>` is a type argument, used in [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html), specifying some type which will be useful later.  For example, in a container class, you don't know what will go in it when you first write it, but your implementation cares about what's in it.

Normally, you'll see something like this:

```
List somelist = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //or some other type
```

meaning that the `ArrayList` will hold `Integers`.  Of course, the implementation stays the same regardless of what type you put in in place of `Integer`, but Java requires you to declare the types of all your referenced objects.  (or you could be lazy and just say it's an `Object`, but that breaks the usefulness of the typing system.)

At other times, you may see

```
class Queue<T> {
   private LinkedList<T> items = new LinkedList<T>();
   public void enqueue(T item) {
      items.addLast(item);
   }
   public T dequeue() {
      return items.removeFirst();
   }
   public boolean isEmpty() {
      return (items.size() == 0);
   }
}
```

(taken from [Javanotes](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c10/s5.html)).  The variable `T` in the class definition captures the type passed in, and `T` can be used in place of whatever type was passed in.  For example, the method `dequeue` returns some object, but specifically of type `T`, which is only known after the class is written.  In the method `enqueue`, you want some object to add to your queue, but specifically of the type `T`, which you don't know until you instantiate an instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

< E > is a place holder for a "type" that will be passed in. This is the type that a list will hold. For example the implementation on an arrayList. When you want to create a new array list you need to pass in the object type that the list will hold.

ArrayList example = new ArrayList ();

if we were to look at the arrayList class it would be something like this

public class ArrayList < E > {...}

basically it is saying we will hold a list of some "type" but that type must be passed in at compile time and will not be known until then

Comment: You may want to rewrite your answer. It's not very clear at the moment, i.e. "The type of that list" - you really mean "the type of object which the list will contain"...

Answer (score 0):

`<E>` in generics is simply a place holder for the generic type.

This is necessary because you need some kind of a reference in the method or class you are writing in order to make use of the type in the return type etc.

You will many examples if you just take a look at the collection API.

Generally if you have just `E` you can pass whatever Type as that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`<E>` is a type parameter. Just like a variable can hold values, a type parameter holds types. For example, If you want to create a class that contains two values of *any* type with **type safety**, you would do:

```
class Pair<T1, T2> {
    private final T1 first;
    private final T2 second;

    public Pair(final T1 first, final T2 second) {
      this.first = first;
      this.second = second;
    }

    public T1 first() {return first;}

    public T2 second() {return second;}

    public static <A, B> Pair<A, B> of(final A first, final B second) {
        return new Pair<A, B>(first, second);
    }
}
```

Here we have used type parameters in two places: one for the class to abstract over the field types and one for the static factory method `of` to abstract over the types of pairs it creates. We can make use of this class like:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Pair<Integer, String> intStringPair = Pair.of(1, "One");
    final int intStringPairFirst = intStringPair.first();
    final String intStringPairSecond = intStringPair.second();

    final Pair<List<String>, Boolean> listBoolPair = Pair.of(
            Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"), true);
    final List<String> listBoolPairFirst = listBoolPair.first();
    final boolean listBoolPairSecond = listBoolPair.second();
}
```

Here you can see how the types for `intStringPairFirst`, `intStringPairSecond`, `listBoolPairFirst`, `listBoolPairSecond` are correctly inferred without involving any casts.

This is to get you started. There are more things to it like variance, bounds using `extends` and `super` and wildcard (`?`) for which I suggest you read on a tutorial on generics.